# Question on Implicit function

Tags: functions, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function

**Question - Show that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}~\frac{\partial Ⲫ }{\partial z}~\frac{dz}{dx}=~\frac{\partial f }{\partial x}~\frac{\partial Ⲫ  }{\partial y}~,$$where $~f(x,y)=0;~~ Ⲫ (z,y)=0~.$**

---

**Sol.** In the function $~f(x,y)=0~,~~ y~$ is an implicit function of $~x~$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{\partial f }{\partial x }}{\frac{\partial f }{\partial y}}$$

**And the solution goes on...**

My query is “In the function $~f(x,y)=0~, ~~y~$ is an implicit function of $~x~$”
, how we know that $~y~$ is an implicit function of $~x~$?

Comment: From where you got this ? Provide the context.

Comment: My book. I'm a BSc student

Comment: I don't want to know that, provide us the full pages of you book from where you got this.

Comment: (https://imgur.com/YKn7lqY )(https://imgur.com/B1JMxP6)
 (https://imgur.com/NIDfS38)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explicit Function:** A function in which the dependent variable, and independent variable are separated on opposite sides of the equality are known as explicit function.

i.e., If a function is written (or can be written) as $~y=f(x)~$, then it is explicit.

e.g., Take $~x^2+y^2-1=0~$, solving for $~y~$ gives an explicit solution: $~y=\pm \sqrt{1-x^2}~$.

**Implicit Function:** A function in which the dependent variable, and independent variable(s) are not separated (isolated) on opposite sides of the equality are known as implicit function.

i.e., If it only has the form $~f(x,y)=0~$, then it is implicit.

e.g., Take $~x^2 + xy~ – y^2 = 1~$, then $~f(x,y)=x^2 + xy~ – y^2-1=0~$.

****************************-

I think my above discussion will clear your doubt.  You can also see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function).

Comment: So, according to my question we can also say that x is an implicit function of y?

Comment: Yes, you can. Then it is $$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{\frac{\partial f }{\partial y}}{\frac{\partial f }{\partial x}}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have to use the [Implicit Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).

We consider the curve defined by $f(x, y)=0$. Now, pick two points $x_0$ and $y_0$ such that $f(x_0,y_0)=0$. If it holds
$$
\left.
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\right|_{(x_0, y_0)} \neq 0,
$$
then there exists a differentiable function $y(x)$ such that, for $x$ close to $x_0$,
$$
f(x, y(x)) = 0.
$$

In particular,
$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = \frac{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
}{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
}.
$$

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry,I don't get it

Comment: Which part is giving you trouble?

Comment: “We consider the curve defined by f(x,y)=0”. - okay, “Now, pick two points x0 and y0 such that f(x0,y0)=0” - okay, i have considered function $x^2-y^2=0$ and point is $(1,1)$. I don't get the later part

Comment: And yes i'm familiar with this formaula. I don't get the stuff b/w the formula and after the **text** i have written in above comment.